# Windows 7 - Changing domain prefix for different wired networks?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wired-networking, network-profiles

I have two wired networks that I connect to regularly with my laptop.

Both of them have different DNS servers

My home network has a router that I have configured with DNSMasq, and I use a static IP when I'm there.

The other network doles me out an IP address, and adds me to a domain (it's a Windows domain controller).

What I'm trying to avoid here is reconfiguring the wired NIC every time I switch between the two networks.

Now I understand that if you go into `Network and Sharing Center` and click the icon next to the network name that you are presently connected to, you can get a list of Managed and Unmanaged networks.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to make a network "managed", which I assume means that your nic  will be auto-configured to it upon connection.

Is there some way be sure that my static IP/DNS server/domain prefix is maintained when I am home, and when I go to the other wired network I can be configured to that networks domain controller etc?